# REQUEST_DENIED Google Maps API v3 Places Error

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places in Google Maps API v3, but I get the following error: REQUEST_DENIED. My URI is: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=47.1738409069289,27.574825862967&radius=1000&name=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA5aYxMm7RoYGwoha1oDHVRXbPxF0Ep0vk

After reading this: [REQUEST_DENIED when using the Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427980/request-denied-when-using-the-google-places-api) and this: [Google Places API - REQUEST_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060563/google-places-api-request-denied) , I got another key, set the sensor to false and true and I still get the same error.

Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Chirs Green can you please give me a solutions for my [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809338/how-to-use-google-places-auto-complete-for-wp7) regarding places autocomplete in wp7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have not activated the Places API service in your API's Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console.

Please follow the directions here to activate the service: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication

You might want to consider generating a new API key now that you have posted it on here to avoid abuse of the service under your account. Always keep your API key safe and secure.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your old application and create new application and enable place api , then you will get api key in "Api Access".,It works for me

Comment: can you please give me a solutions for my [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809338/how-to-use-google-places-auto-complete-for-wp7) regarding places autocomplete in wp7

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue from last few days,

Please go to, https://code.google.com/apis/console  and create new application and enable place api , then you will get api key in "Api Access".