# Google Places API - Attempted Solution

Tags: google-places-api

There seems to be some confusion as to what is causing an error with Google Places API and using JSON as the output.

For example, the output (when pasting the URL into the address abr of your browser returns this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

At first, I thought this may have something to do with my API Access Status set to 'Inactive' but after reading several posts here on SO...

- [REQUEST_DENIED Google Maps API v3 Places Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385990/request-denied-google-maps-api-v3-places-error)
- [Google Places API - REQUEST_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060563/google-places-api-request-denied)
- [REQUEST_DENIED when using the Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427980/request-denied-when-using-the-google-places-api)

...I am none the wiser. The aim of this post/thread is to try establish exactly the capabilities of Google Places API, whether or not the API Key is required, and why `REQUEST_DENIED` occurs so often for many users.

Comment: Thanks for the amendments Roddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"` is returned when:

- The `sensor` parameter is missing
- The `key` parameter is missing
- The `sensor` parameter is not set to `true` or `false`
- There is a problem with the `key` parameter e.g.

  - You have not activated the Places API Service in your [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) Services Tab
  - Your API Key does not match the key in your [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) API Access Tab
  - Your API key has been compromised and blocked; you can generate a new API key in your [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) API Access Tab
- The request is not sent as a `HTTPS GET` request

  - `HTTPS` is required for all Places API Web Service request
  - `POST` requests will only work for Places API [Place Actions](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions) e.g Check-In and Event requests

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This is exactly the answer I needed. I think my problem  was the GET request method. I had been simply copying & pasting the url string into a new browser window expecting to see a plethora of results. Looks like I still have a bit of work to do ;)