# how to use google places auto-complete for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocomplete, google-places-api

Am developing a simple app in that i need to get places auto-complete when user typing some city name

how to use [this](http://gplaceswp7.codeplex.com/documentation)

or any another apis, solutions to achive this

thnaks in advance