# Approval process of a place added with Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I added places with the Google Places API (Web Service) some weeks ago.

How does the approval work and 
how long does it take till a place has passed Google moderation and is approved?
How do I know if a place was declined?

I added an other place with the Google Maps Maker. This place was approved within a week. What's the difference?

Comment: what is your working platform. add this as your tag .

Comment: I used the Google Places API Web Service and added the place with a REST call. Everthing worked fine: Getting back an "OK" and a place id and scope APP

Comment: Obviously, Google let this API die. I have the same issues. A lot of places added using their API and no moderation from Google, no news, no usefull answer on gmaps issues. By the way, the endpoint return an error since few days.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons why we are receiving  ['REQUEST_DENIED'](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied)
* You have not activated the Google Places API Web Service in the Google Developers Console.
* The key parameter is missing from your request.
* The key parameter does not match the your API key in the Google Developers Console.
* Your API key has not been correctly set up in the Google Developers Console:
* The request was not sent as an HTTPS request, HTTPS is required for all Google Places API Web Service requests.
* The incorrect HTTP method was used to send the request:

Double check all listed above then try to execute your application.

The newly-added place is available to your app after a short time, and is added to a moderation queue for possible addition to Google's Places database and Google Maps. Places that pass moderation will be visible to all apps and on Google Maps.

When you add a place, you receive a place ID for the new place immediately. This place ID is scoped for your app only. The place then enters a moderation queue, awaiting approval for addition to the Google Places database. If approved, the place will receive a new place ID, available to all apps and on Google Maps.

Here are related stack overflow ticket: [REQUEST_DENIED when using the Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427980/request-denied-when-using-the-google-places-api) / [Google Places API - REQUEST_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060563/google-places-api-request-denied)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The problem is not that I don't get the request. For clarification: I added some Places and got for them  OK status in the response and placeId and the scope APP. This is all perfect. My problem is the place are not getting approved by Google. I have waited now for three weeks. Maybe takes longer I don't know what the process ob the Google site is.