# Could not fetch Places - REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to fetch places from google place api, I just download [SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete) & created new API Key enable place, direction & map api's from Google API Console still i am getting error alert.

[image]

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I think your google api key is not valid. Check in google api console.

Comment: I have checked 2/3 times but not works. Even  checked with restriction still :( doesn't  works.

Comment: also check bundle id with restriction key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using key which is made for iOS apps.But `SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete` might be using Google's public API to fetch the places list. So in that case you should **use key for your browser apps**. You can refer following link for more elaborated ans

[REQUEST_DENIED when using the Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427980/request-denied-when-using-the-google-places-api)

Comment: Simple & short i will say update answer only & write words `Create api key from` [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1,000 free requests per 24 hour period.

The "status": "REQUEST_DENIED" is returned by the Google Places API Web Service when:

You have not activated the Google Places API Web Service in the Google API Console.

The key parameter is missing from your request. EX. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY

The key parameter does not match the your API key in the Google API Console.
Your API key has not been correctly set up in the Google API Console:

- If you are using a browser-restricted API key, check that your
  allowed referer(s) are correct.
- If you are using a server-restricted API key, check that your allowed
  IP(s) are correct.
- API keys with Android or iOS restrictions are not supported. Please
  use a generic (unrestricted) API key, or a key with browser or server
  restrictions.

The request was not sent as an HTTPS request, HTTPS is required for all Google Places API Web Service requests.

The incorrect HTTP method was used to send the request:

- All requests must be sent as a GET request except for Place Add.
- All Place Add requests must be sent as a POST request.

Comment: Thank you harshal for your efforts @i have accepted Ankit answer your 3rd point that i was not aware about it. :)

Comment: Hi Harshal i am asking one more question on google places please answer me it seems you are master in Google place i'll accept your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Create API Key from this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) & from google console make sure you have enabled Google Place API.